# How could I conceal exposed outlet wiring after electric baseboard heater removal?

Tags: trim, trim-carpentry

Had a forced air system installed to replace the expensive baseboard heating that couldn't keep up with demand.

I am going through and removing all the baseboards now and pulling all the wiring via the basement but this spot is extra ugly due to the two outlet boxes. How would professionals fix this up? I would like it to follow code.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some ideas, in order of preference:

- Drop the wiring down from each box, under the floor (which would allow you to remove the shelf board)
- Bring the wiring up under the shelf board where it's mostly hidden.
- Overlay a one-by board with a minimal gap behind (maybe right behind the blocks on which the faceplates are mounted)
- Run Wiremold™ or similar in beige or tan